# Can storing a set of pointers lead to undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11, set

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

  std::set<int*> ints;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
    int * k = new int(i);
    ints.insert(k);
  }

  for (auto i : ints) {
    // some order-sensitive operations, for example:
    std::cout << (*i) << " ";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Where the second loop is sensitive to the order in which elements are taken from the set. Is it possible that the result of execution of such program will be different in different runs of the program?

As far as I know, `std::set` sorts elements internally. Since allocations in memory not necessarily have increasing addresses, it is possible (though unlikely), that the output of this program will not be `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`?

Comment: I'd say that even if the order may not be deterministic, it's still not undefined behaviour in the usual sense (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @Pukku Yeah, I used the wrong term. Its closer to "unspecified" behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they may be different, but it will not be because of UB.

There are two things that are implementation defined here:

- the way `std::less<int*>` does the ordering (although on most implementations you will see a "natural" ordering)
- The addresses that are returned by `operator new` may or may not be the same every time. This will most likely vary on the allocator your implementation use, and both ways (deterministic and seemingly random) have been seen in the wild. (Note that when you run the program through e.g. valgrind the order may still be always the same, but different than when run natively).

So do not rely on this being in any particular order you are interested in.

Answer (score 2):

It's not "undefined behavior" in the standard's sense (that *anything* can happen).

However, it is definitely unspecified what pointer addresses you will get when allocating memory. The standard says nothing about how the free store is organized, or the order of addresses for different allocations.

Answer (score 0):

Use the manual, Luke.

[std::set documentation in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/e8wh7665%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> An STL set is:
>
> (...)
>
> Sorted, because its elements are ordered by key values within the container in accordance with a specified comparison function.

The pointers are simply ints, so these variables will be sorted by their addresses. Memory manager can allocate these variables in very different places, so you have no guarantee, that their order (in terms of their values) will be kept.

However, it seems, that you can provide your own comparison function:

[std::set::set() documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yy2xd0h.aspx)

You then may sort the elements of set in a way, which fits you best.

Comment: For the described Microsoft implementation, it is true that pointers are almost ints - except on Win64, where they're not. On other architectures, pointers can be even less int-like. The most famous exception is classical x86, where they're weird 20 bits beasts.